# Headphone Buttons and USB-C Adapters

Tags: buttons, headphones

I owe a which doesn't have a 3.5mm headphone jack. Instead, it use my headphones with a USB-C to 3.5mm adapter. While the speakers and the mic work, the buttons don't. They're assigned incorrect functions. `Play/Pause` works, but `Vol+` decreases the volume and `Vol-` selects things on the screen.

I wanna change this behaviour. Using the app "KeyEvent Display", I figured out that

- `Vol+` triggers "linux key code number" 114
- `Vol-`  triggers "linux key code number" 259
- `Play/Pause`  triggers "linux key code number" 226

Using the [android documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files), I figured out that the buttons are all managed by `/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl`. I could get the expected behaviour by changing the following lines:

```
key 114 VOLUME_UP
key 226 HEADSETHOOK
key 259 VOLUME_DOWN
```

However, this interfered with the function of other buttons of my phone!

That's why I want to create a device-specific config file. **For this, I need either the device name or the vendor and product IDs.** (As explained in the android documentation.) However, I don't know to get those. The app "USB Device Info" didn't show any connected device. This is the shortened output of `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`:

```
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0003 Version=2061
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=0100
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
```

Full output: [here](https://pastebin.com/902uEcUn).

Relevant output of "Under the Hood": `pastebin.com/kDeBNS0H`

I made a file containing the above code and tried giving it the following file names (rebooting every time): `Vendor_0000_Product_0003.kl`, `Vendor_0000_Product_0000.kl`, `Vendor_0001_Product_0001.kl`, but nothing worked.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is the converter active (digital), or passive (analog)? If you don't know, the price might be a hint.

Comment: I think it's passive.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [keytest](https://github.com/chrisboyle/keytest) app, I found out that the device ID of the headphones     (2) differed from the device ID of the regular volume buttons (7 and 3).
Now, I only had to find out the device name corresponding to the device ID. This I did using a terminal emulator:

```
$ su
$ getevent
add device 1: /dev/input/event7
name: "msm8976-skun-snd-card Headset Jack"
add device 2: /dev/input/event6
name: "msm8976-skun-snd-card Button Jack"
add device 3: /dev/input/event4
name: "qpnp_pon"
add device 4: /dev/input/event3
name: "qwerty"
could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse1, Not a typewriter
add device 5: /dev/input/event2
name: "hbtp_vm"
add device 6: /dev/input/event1
name: "input_mt_wrapper"
could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
add device 7: /dev/input/event5
name: "gpio-keys"
could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
add device 8: /dev/input/event0
name: "synaptics_dsx_s2"
```

According to the [documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files), all characters other than `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z` and `-` are replaced by `_`. Thus, I created a new file: `/system/usr/keylayout/msm8976-skun-snd-card_Button_Jack.kl` with the following content:

```
# Configuration file for LeEco Le 2 headphone buttons
key 114 VOLUME_UP
key 226 HEADSETHOOK
key 259 VOLUME_DOWN
```

After a reboot, I got the expected behaviour!